# ModuleNotFoundError (for bs4), when using command line to run Python program created on PyCharm?

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm

I am doing the Automate the Boring Stuff course, which frequently features the use of the command line and batch files to quickly run Python programs.
The current example I am following along with (searchpypi) requires the installation of the 'bs4' module. I installed it, firstly by rightclicking the module name and clicking the red lightbulb, then clicking install 'bs4'.
When I run the code in PyCharm, there are no issues.

However, when I use the command line to run the .bat file that contains the path to the program, I get this message:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

I googled around, and one of the suggestions was to install bs4 by going to PyCharm's File Interpreter and adding the package. But that resulted in the same error with the command line.
Then I tried using the terminal, and running this line:
python -m pip install bs4.
That resulted in the same error.

Is this due to me using a virtual environment? Something to do with system-wide python installation? I really don't know. Any input would be appreciated!

[This shows the status of the bs4 installation, when I use PyCharm's terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxUDJ.png)

EDIT: This is the code in PyCharm.

```
    #!python3
#searchpypi - Opens several search results

import requests, webbrowser, sys, bs4
print('searching...')
response = requests.get(
    'https://google.com/search?q=',
    'https://pypi.org/search/?q='
    + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
    )

response.raise_for_status()
contents = response.text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(contents,'html.parser')
all_a_tags = soup.select('.package-snippet')
numOpen = min(5, len(all_a_tags))
for i in range(numOpen):
    URLToOpen = 'https://pypi.org' + all_a_tags[i].get('href')
    print('Opening', URLToOpen)
    webbrowser.open(URLToOpen)
```

This is the code in my batchfile. When I use Windows Run and type the name of the batchfile, followed by key words, it opens the command prompt and runs the PyCharm code.

```
@py C:\Users\USERNAME\PycharmProjects\chapter12\searchpypi\main.py %*

@pause
```

Comment: Can you show us the code? And are you sure that you're using right interpreter?
As i can see, you have bs4 installed in venv, ensure that your .bat script is running your virtual environment

Comment: Hello, I've edited my post to show the PyCharm code and the text in the batch file.

To be honest, I don't know how to change the interpreter for my batch file. Also, I feel like I made a mistake somewhere, if bs4 was installed in venv, and not system-wide; how could I make bs4 system-wide? I'm pretty new to the concept of venv and system-wide installations, but I think I've been using venv for all my PyCharm codes so far; is this a problem if I want to run batchfiles and command lines?

Answer (score 0):

`Win+R -> cmd -> Enter -> python -m pip install beautifulsoup4` should install beautiful soup for your "system-wide" python.

You already have beautifulsoup4 installed in your venv, so you can use it instead:

```
# your .bat file
@echo off
cmd /k "cd /d C:\Users\USERNAME\PycharmProjects\chapter12\searchpypi2\venv\Scripts & activate & cd /d    C:\Users\USERNAME\PycharmProjects\chapter12\searchpypi2 & python main.py"
```

Or you can run your program using PyCharm, so you need to [configure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) your python interpreter.

P.S. i noticed that you have your project in 'searchpypi2' folder, but your .bat script runs program in 'searchpypi' folder. This might be the case.

Comment: Yes, I think it's working now. Thank you for teaching me how to pip install in the CMD! I had to set a new path in environment variables in order to use the python keyword. 

I think your second method works as well, but I don't understand it well. 
Could you explain why there are two different C:\ paths (or send a link to a guide?)
I wish I could upvote your answer but I'm too new ):

Comment: Its not really different paths. You have your project virtual environment in your project folder. At first you need to activate venv `venv/Scripts/activate`, then you need to run your python script `python main.py`.
You can find more info about venvs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

Answer (score -1):

I also got stumped when using the exercise in Automate the Boring stuff.  I am using it on a Pi4, standard OS install, but my problem was different to the one above.

The program would run, but would not open up any windows.  Using the debugger I found that the numOpen variable was always 0, which meant it was not finding any of the right tags.

I realised quickly that search term was going to Google, which doesn't have the package-snippet tag.  So if you remove the following code:

'https://google.com/search?q=',

The program works fine, well it does for me anyway.